# unable to pass text field value to controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create comments for a product. Somehow I'm unable to pass the value in text_field back to comments controller. The comment is created in database, but the body column of the table is not populated.

My product model looks like this -

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

My Comment model looks like this -

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product

end
```

My Comments controller looks is given below -

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create

@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@comment = @product.comments.build(body: params[:comment_body])
@comment.user_id = session[:user_id]
@comment.product_id = params[:product_id]
if @comment.save

            redirect_to selection_path(params[:product_id])
        else
            redirect_to selection_path(params[:product_id]), notice: "Please include a plain text comment only"
        end
      end
      private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(comments_attributes: [ :body,:product_id ])
        end
    end
```

Routes are given below -

```
get "store/prodselect/:id" => 'store#prodselect', as: :selection
resources :products do
get :who_bought, on: :member
post "comments/create" => 'comments#create', as: :create_comment
end
```

I'm able to show the comments in prodselect.html.erb using the following code -

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<tr>        
<td class="tbody" style="width:150px;"><%= comment.uname %>
    <%= image_tag @product.user.pic.url(:thumb), :width=>50, :height=>50 %>
</td>
    <td class="tbody" style="width:350px;"><%= comment.body %></td>
</tr>   
<% end %>
```

This is the place where I'm unable to pass text_field value back to comments controller. The below code and the code above are in prodselect.html.erb. Also prodselect is a method in Store controller -

```
<tr><td>                    
<%= text_field :comment, :body%>
<%= button_to 'Add comment' , product_create_comment_path(@product.id), :class => "buttonto" %>
</td></tr>
```

Finally my prodselect method in store controller looks like this -

```
def prodselect
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.where(product_id: params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

I'm new to ror, so any pointers will be appreciated. I would like to know why I'm unable to pass my text field value to my comments controller. I've tried using text_area as well unsuccessfully.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post your full form? There are a lot of things messed up in your code

Comment: Can you post `params` that are coming to your controller action? you can find it on rails server terminal

Comment: HI, This is the params being passed in the log - "comment"=>{"body"=>"Great Comment"} . How can I access the value in controller ?

Answer (score 0):

[button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) creates a form in itself just posting to the url (I'll admit I've explained that poorly so go and look at the documentation linked), so your text field isn't actually part of the form and thus not passed.  You will need to use an actual form

```
<tr>
  <td> 
    <%= form_for [@product, Comment.new] do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
      <%= f.submit 'Add comment', :class => "buttonto" %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: HI, I get an error message when I try to use form_for in a partial. The message is 'NoMethodError in Store#prodselect' . Showing E:/demo/app/views/store/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `product_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x5346f48>:0x4d1dc98>

Comment: `<%= form_for [@product, Comment.new], url: create_comment_product_path do |f| %>` I assume looking at your routes, if not rake routes and see what the path for your comment creation is and use that in the url option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using form_for or anything like that? Your button_to with just the path will not sent the information to your controller. Try to read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes my path in routes was incorrect. Also form_for helped. Thanks for pointing me to right direction.